# AWS Beanstalk execute specific command

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a sample node.js application that only works with sqlite.
I want to do a 'proof of concept' on AWS ElasticBeanstalk without rewriting the node.js app to work with a supported database

In order for the node.js app to start, I must first seed the sqlite database by executing `node db.js`.

How can I execute this node command on an EBS instance?

I have tried adding a command to .ebextensions

.ebextensions/foo.config

```
commands:
  1_seed_db:
    command: "PATH=$PATH:`ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin node db.js"
```

Which returns error:

> Error: Cannot find module '/var/app/current/db.js;'

I suspect /var/app/current directory doesn't exist yet, so I've also tried modifying the NodeCommand so it executes a custom command `node db.js; npm start` [as documented here:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html)

.ebextensions/node.config

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs
    option_name: NodeCommand
    value: node db.js; npm start
```

How can I make Elastic beanstalk execute `node db.js` before starting the node process?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by spoofing the start command in packages.json

packages.json before:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
```

packages.json after:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./db.js; node ./bin/www"
},
```

You obviously shouldn't do this in production, but it works well enough for a proof of concept.